# Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073741819

Tags: android, flutter, windows, dart

```
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -1073741819

Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 283452 to 3360 bytes (98.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 5208 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

Target android_aot_release_android-arm failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code -1073741819

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* Where:

Script 'C:\\src\\flutter\\packages\\flutter_tools\\gradle\\src\\main\\groovy\\flutter.groovy' line: 1350

\* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

\\\> Process 'command 'C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried to build an APK with Flutter, and this error happened.

I was trying to build an APK using Flutter, and this problem appeared.

Make me reinstall Windows.

Comment: did you tried adding this flag "--no-tree-shake-icons"? try building it like this : flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons